# Unable to create Dojo custom widget for certain attributes

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to create a custom ValidationTextBox widget for an email address.  We have many areas in our system where we use an email address input and I want to create one widget that has the default regex, invalid messages, etc.  The problem is there are two attributes:  placeholder and maxlength that do not seem to be getting added to my extended class.  My code is as follows:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", // declare
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], 
function(declare, ValidationTextBox, lang){  

    return lang.mixin(ValidationTextBox, {
    invalidMessage: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    missingMessage: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    regExp : "[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$",
    maxlength : 50,
    placeholder : 'Your Email'
    });
});
```

If I use this on my page, the invalid messages work fine, but anywhere I use this, I do not see a placeholder, nor is a maxlength applied.  In addition to the lang.mixin approach, I've also tried using the declare approach spelled out here:  http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/07/01/creating-and-enhancing-dojo-classes/.  I get the same result.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See both options you described in action at http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/eLkwb/

Use [`dojo/_base/lang::extend`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/lang#extend) instead of `mixin`:

```
lang.extend(ValidationTextBox, {
    invalidMessage: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    missingMessage: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    pattern: "[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$",
    required: true,
    maxLength: 3,
    placeHolder : 'Your Email'
});
```

Also please note:

- `regExp` is deprecated, use `pattern` instead
- attributes are case sensitive: so `placeHolder`, `maxLength`
- make sure to `dojo/parser::parse()` after the extension took place (for markup instantiation)
- `maxLength` does not work for some reason (see `declare` workaround below)

Accomplishing the same **via subclassing**:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
], function(
    declare,          
    ValidationTextBox
) {

    return declare([ValidationTextBox], {
        postCreate: function() {
            // a workaround to make maxLength working
            this.inherited(arguments);            
            this.set("maxLength", this.maxLength);
        },            
        invalidMessage: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        missingMessage: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        pattern: "[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$",
        required: true,
        maxLength: 3,
        placeHolder : 'Your Email'
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  In regards to the case sensitivity, we actually have numerous places in the application where we're using 'placeholder' and 'maxlength' and it seems to work fine.  In addition, if I use placeHolder as you mention, I see the font in italics, when its not italicized anywhere else in our app.